# Grails equivalent for Gradle Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, gradle, ggts

I just cloned a Grails project to my local machine (using Mercurial). I am using GGTS for Grails projects, and would like to import the Grails project as an existing project. With a Gradle-built project, I would just apply the Gradle Eclipse plugin and then run `gradle eclipse` inside the project root.

This generates Eclipse project files and classpath magic for me, so I can import it into my Eclipse workspace.

I'm using GGTS for my Grails projects. But when I open up GGTS and go to Import >> Existing project, and select my Grails project (root dir), it doesn't see the necessary Eclipse project files and can't open it up.

So I ask: is there an equivalent "Grails Eclipse/GGTS" plugin that will allow me to take a Grails project that has no Eclipse files (`.project`, etc.) and generate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you are looking for is the Grails command `integrate-with`. You can read more about it in the Grails [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/integrate-with.html).

> The integrate-with command will integrate Grails with different IDEs
>   and build systems based on the arguments provided. For example the
>   --eclipse command will produce .project and .classpath files for use with Eclipse or Spring Tool Suite (STS).

Comment: Boom! Like Flow would say, "nailed it!"